# How to automate VPS server creation and configuration?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, installation, automation

I encountered a problem with my current hosting provider. I have around 30 VPS servers, which were all configured manually after purchase. There is no API access for my plan and soon i will have to expand my infrastructure up to several hundred of VPS servers which can't be done manually (ideally a snapshot?).

The default linux distributions (debian) were enhanced with additional packages (dozens of them), like apache, percona-server, git, qt5-default, proftpd, phantomjs (this one manually compiled), to name a few. Also, some manual changes in config files were made.

I actually have a text file with a list of all copy/paste actions, which i perform robotically-like after purchasing new server.

How to start automating this process? I will have a CSV or DB with a list of server IP, SSH logins and passwords. Should i start with remote SSH login and perhaps execute a bash script afterwards? That one could be downloaded from some predefined location on a target machine.

My biggest challenges are auto-editing the config files, filling password queries while installing percona-sql, proftpd and adding usernames. Also, auto-yes when using apt-get install.

Is there a framework for such things? Any help greatly appreciated.

My plan so far:

1. create a list of servers (with IP, SSH login + password)
2. write a bash (or other language?) script to log in to each of the servers
3. while on a remote machine, download another bash script there, and execute it
4. this latter script installs apache, percona-sql, proftpd, creates users, edits config files, etc.
5. log out, proceed to next server

Step number 4 is something i need most help with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you take a look at configuration management tools like `Saltstack` or `Ansible`. It is the way to go if you want to automate an infrastructure. It will take some time to learn, but trust me you will save much more time with the level of automation they provide.

With `Saltstack` for example, you will have one `salt-master` controlling multiple `salt-minion`s (Your servers?) at the same time.
And it has many modules that can help you with the configuration of almost anything you want.

So, with only one command you will be able to do what you want on all of your servers. You will only need to install an agent (salt-minion) on your servers in order to be able to control them or you can use Saltstack with SSH.

Have a look at the docs [here](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/).

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't want to be doing all that configuration manually, what you want to take some time to learn about is known as [DevOps](http://devops.com/2014/04/02/introductiontodevops/).

> DevOps is predicated on the idea that all elements of technology infrastructure can be controlled through code. With the rise of the cloud it can all be done in real-time via a web service. Infrastructure automation solves the problem of having to be physically present in a data center to provision hardware and make network changes

If you take a look at the **Configuration Management** section you will see there are many different tools/frameworks to automate your infrastructure.

[Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/) is a popular one. DZone has an awesome [refcard on Chef](https://dzone.com/refcardz/chef-open-source-tool-scalable) which gives a **complete overview** of the basics to help you get started. The chef website itself also has some great [tutorials](https://learn.chef.io/tutorials/).